# How does python's random module generate a random number?

Tags: python, math, random

I want to know how the random.py module does to generate a random number?  I read the random.py file but I did not understand the comments.  does it use a mathematical property?  Is it possible to create own random.py?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for `random.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Python uses the [***Mersenne Twister***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) as the core generator. It produces
> 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying
> implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister
> is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in
> existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable
> for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic
> purposes.

(emphasis and hyperlinking mine)